# битый pdf на выходе из DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

на выходе из dompdf получают битый pdf-файл, который невозможно открыть. в преобразовании использую parsedown для преобразования md-текста в html, далее dompdf для преобразования html в pdf.

```
            $parsedown = new Parsedown();
            $htmlReady = $parsedown->text("**ehheh**");

                $dompdf = new Dompdf();
                $dompdf -> set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
                $dompdf -> loadHtml($htmlReady);
                $dompdf -> render();
                $dompdf -> stream(rand(1,1000000), array("Attachment" => 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Кому надо:
 Перед использованием метода stream() надо отключать буферизацию. Все будет работать после откл. буфера. 
 Т.к. я работаю на bitrix'e, то вот код, который помог мне:

```
$APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
    $dompdf -> stream(rand(1,1000000), array("Attachment" => 1));
die();
```